# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js após atualizar versão do Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Após atualizar a versão do angular de 6.1 para 7, quando fui dar `ng serve` me retorna o seguinte erro:

> "ERROR in ./src/app/components/anuncios/anuncios.component.scss Module
>   build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):"

O que eu tentei:

```
npm i -g sass-loader
```

Removi a node modules e dei `npm install`

Comment: Tenta dar um `npm install node-sass`

Comment: Não mudou nada :/